# How to properly persist login state using FireBase in React Native EXPO?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I used email and password to sign in through Firebase. However, once I reload the app, I need to sign in again. Is there a way to automatically log user in once the app is reloaded?

I am using EXPO managed project with functional structure btw, not with class structure.

Answer (score 0):

if you're still facing this problem.
Here's how I've done it.
Here's my App.js

```
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setLoggedIn);
  }, []);

  if (loggedIn) {
    return <HomeScreen />
  } else {
     <Login /> 
  }
```

Here's the login code.
I have a simple form with email and password and a button, when pressed, this functions is called.

```
  const handleLogin = async () => {
      await firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .catch((err) => {
          setVisible(true);
          setModalMessage(err.message);
        });
    
  };
```

Let me know if this worked.

Comment: Does this work if you close the app and re-open it? I'm looking for a similar solution. ( Here, User Logs-In, Login data is stored, user closes app and reopens, login data is read and user is logged in).